# Connection between rotate / translate / scale as operations in 3D space

Tags: transformation, rotations

This feels like a silly question, what am I missing:

I'm a 3D artist working on videogames.  Sometimes I make 3D artworks like the ones here: http://samuelthomson.org/blog/2012/06/07/topologic-analogies-6-public-sphere-2/

Translating, rotating and scaling are fundamental to working in 3D in programs like blender, 3DSmax, Unity, etc.

In real life, if I pick up a banana I can easily rotate and translate it, but scaling feels impossible. What is the reason for this?

Are translation, rotation, and scale related on some deep fundamental level, in a similar way to angles on a triangle?

This is probably VERY wrong, but I think about things like a banana as a collection of atoms, and atoms as tiny little solar systems, and rotating it, I just fix a point of origin and rotate, and translating I pick a direction and...push.  Anyway, rotating and translating feel like they belong in column A, but scaling feels like it belongs in column B, because it requires a point of origin AND a ...push (in a weird way in my mind) to get it how I want it to be.

And are hypercubes involved because they look like a small cube inside a scaled up cube?

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Are you familiar with linear algebra? The ideas of the rotation and scaling can be succinctly described as linear transformations of 3D space, which may be represented as $3 \times 3$ matrices. Translations can be expressed as well if you allow for affine transformations.

Answer (score 1):

In real life, we can only perform [proper rigid transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_transformation), assuming the object we are transforming is solid. These are maps that preserve distances between points (and thus angles), as well as the handed-ness of objects (i.e., you can't turn an object into a mirror image of itself).

I'm not sure what you are getting at with your question about hypercubes, but they do not look like "a small cube inside a bigger cube" any more than a [3-D cube looks like a small square inside a bigger square](https://images-wixmp-ed30a86b8c4ca887773594c2.wixmp.com/f/0d5c942e-15f8-4032-8d23-e4e9b4446c71/d8maf2e-8754f691-5485-4461-88aa-f38ccea2bacf.gif?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1cm46YXBwOjdlMGQxODg5ODIyNjQzNzNhNWYwZDQxNWVhMGQyNmUwIiwiaXNzIjoidXJuOmFwcDo3ZTBkMTg4OTgyMjY0MzczYTVmMGQ0MTVlYTBkMjZlMCIsIm9iaiI6W1t7InBhdGgiOiJcL2ZcLzBkNWM5NDJlLTE1ZjgtNDAzMi04ZDIzLWU0ZTliNDQ0NmM3MVwvZDhtYWYyZS04NzU0ZjY5MS01NDg1LTQ0NjEtODhhYS1mMzhjY2VhMmJhY2YuZ2lmIn1dXSwiYXVkIjpbInVybjpzZXJ2aWNlOmZpbGUuZG93bmxvYWQiXX0.xCrtpkxILjISMyQuFgsGkncQYOO2JnsKXhwaDuVpoCY).